# Is faking dependencies with interfaces or virtual methods a good design choice?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, oop, isolation-frameworks

I am trying to learn unit testing but there is a design issue resulting from it. Consider class A has a dependency on class B. If you want to create a stub for B in order to unit test A, most isolation frameworks require that B has to be an interface or all the methods used by A must be virtual. B can't be a concrete class with non-virtual methods in essence in order to unit test.

This imposes major restrictions on the design of production code. If I have to create an interface for every dependency then number of classes will double. Following Single Responsibility Principle leads to small classes that depend on each other so this will blow up the number of interfaces. Also I create interfaces for volatile dependencies(likely to change in the future) or if the design requires it for extensibility. Polluting the production code with interfaces just for testing will increase its complexity significantly.
Making all methods virtual doesn't seem to be a good solution either. It gives inheritors the impression that these methods are ok to be overridden even if they aren't and in reality this is just a side effect of unit testing.

Does this mean that testable object oriented design doesn't allow concrete dependencies or does it mean that concrete dependencies shouldn't be faked? "Every dependency must be faked(stub or mock) to unit test correctly" is what I learned so far so I don't think latter is the case. Isolation frameworks other than JustMock and Isolator doesn't allow faking concrete dependencies without virtual methods and some argue that power of JustMock and Isolator lead to bad design. I think that the ability to mock any class is very powerful and it will keep the design of production code clean if you know what you are doing.

Comment: "This imposes major restrictions on the design of production code" - are they valid restrictions? If you consider that the trade off (there is always a trade off) is that you get programmatic automated testing (I.E. unit tests, but not limited to just that), then the restrictions seem more than valid.

Comment: It seems to me that the damage is not worth it. Because unit tests should cover entire code base, every dependency should be faked and this seems like a major problem. A class needs to change just because it becomes a dependency for another class. Imagine a developer wrote a class thinking and designing the public interface and access modifier for each method(probably making some methods virtual for inheritance) After a few days you change all the methods of his class to virtual because you wrote a class that calls his methods and a fake is needed for unit testing

Comment: "Damage", "Pollution" - I think you are just ranting about having to update an existing code base to support automated programmatic testing. I understand your pain, and have had to do it before, and will likely have to do it again.  There is a value in doing this (and to what extent you make things testable) that you are going to have to decide for yourself the worth of. 100% coverage is not realistic in most cases. Can you get 80% of the most important parts? That may be a more realistic goal.

Comment: I have no intention to rant. I am asking this because this effects ALL of production code and I can't isolate this bad practice. I know it is unfair to ask an isolation framework for something that can't be done by hand.I think I have to pay for JustMock that allows what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized later that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691725/mocking-objects-declare-all-methods-as-virtual-or-use-interface?rq=1) also asks the same and there seems to have no solution. Choosing between creating an interface or making all methods virtual is a restriction of C# which is statically typed language. Duck-typed language such as Ruby doesn't impose this and a fake object can easily be created without changing the original class. In Ruby fake object just needs to create the appropriate methods and it can be used instead of the original dependency.

Edit:

I finished reading the book The Art of Unit Testing by Roy Osherove and found that the following paragraphs are related:

> Testable designs usually only matter in static languages, such as C# or VB.NET,
>   where testability depends on proactive design choices that allow things to be replaced.
>   Designing for testability matters less in more dynamic languages, where things are
>   much more testable by default. In such languages, most things are easily replaceable,
>   regardless of the project design. This rids the community of such languages from the
>   straw-man argument that the lack of testability of code means it’s badly designed and
>   lets them focus on what good design should achieve, at a deeper level.
>
> Testable designs have virtual methods, nonsealed classes, interfaces, and a clear
>   separation of concerns. They have fewer static classes and methods, and many more
>   instances of logic classes. In fact, testable designs correlate to SOLID design principles
>   but don’t necessarily mean you have a good design. Perhaps it’s time that the end goal
>   should not be testability but good design alone.

This basically means that making the design testable because of the restrictions of a static language doesn't make it a "good design" inherently. For me a good design accomplishes what is needed for today's requirements and doesn't think about future too much. Of course making every dependency abstract is good for maintainability in the future but it makes the API very complex. I want to make a dependency an interface if its likely to change or many concrete classes implement that interface not because testability requires it. Doing this because testability requires it leads to "bad design".